# Javascript: assign/pass a value to a inputbox

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript for slider, my problem is i cant assign/pass the value of the slider to a inputbox. I already tried using this scripT "document.getElementByID('total').value = pos" in my javascript, but it didnt pass anything. any idea guys?  Thanks in advance!

HTML CODE:

```
< input type="hidden" id="total" value="" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" runat="server" />
```

JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() 
    {
        var mySlideB = new Slider($('slider_gutter_1'), $('slider_knob_1'),         $('slider_bkg_img_1'),
        {
            start: 1,
            end: 100,
            offset: 10,
            onChange: function(pos)
            {
                if (pos <= 10) {
                    $('slider_desc_value').setHTML("Not Important");
                }
                else if ((pos >= 11) && (pos <= 40)) {
                    $('slider_desc_value').setHTML("Partially Important");
                }
                else if ((pos >= 41) && (pos <= 60)) {
                    $('slider_desc_value').setHTML("Important");
                }
                else if ((pos >= 61) && (pos <= 85)) {
                    $('slider_desc_value').setHTML("Very Important");
                }
                else if (pos > 85) {
                    $('slider_desc_value').setHTML("Critical to our business");
                }

                $('slider_current_val').setHTML(pos + ' %');
                $('testjp').setHTML(pos);    

                                    // THIS IS NOT WORKING, HELP?
                **document.getElementById('total').value = pos;**

                                    //This work c/o Ravi. THanks!
                                    document.forms["form1"]["total"].value = pos;

            }
        }, null).setMin(1);

        $('slider_current_val').setHTML(100 + ' %');
    });
```

Comment: Try `document.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementByID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead try this, give a name to your input and your form i.e

```
<form name="form"><input type="hidden" name="total"/></form>
```

and try this

```
document.forms["form"]["total"].value = xxx;
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi! this work perfect! finally..


 document.forms["form1"]["total"].value = pos;  =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('#total').val(pos);
```

and check whether your `onChange` function is called by putting an alert inside the function.

change your function like thi,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//your code here...
});
```

instead of `window.addEvent('domready', function()`

Comment: thanks for the quick response. unfortunately, the code you mention didn't pass anything to the inputbox (total). i did also get an error when inspecting the element. "uncaught Typerror; Cannot call method 'val' of null" =(

Comment: check my answer, I think your input doesn't even exist

Answer (score 1):

The input has a runat="server" property, because of this the ASP.Net engine could be assigning the ID.

Just as a suggestion view the source of you application and you will see if the ID has changed.

if so the fix is easy.

```
document.getElementById('<%= total.ClientID %>').value = pos
```

or as the other two answers suggested

```
$('#<%=total.ClientID%>').val(pos);
```

Hope this helps.

regards.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but when i tried the first and second code both didnt pass anything, also noticed the error when i inspected the element of the page "Uncaught Typerror; Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementByID'" and "uncaught Typerror; Cannot call method 'val' of null".. TIA!

Comment: As "Cystack" mentioned, "getElementByID" does not exist. is "getElementById".

Answer (score 0):

why do not you use

```
$('#total').val(pos);
```

It should do the trick

Comment: i already tried that but i didnt pass anything. also got an error when inpecting the element on the page. "uncaught Typerror; Cannot call method 'val' of null".

Answer (score 0):

Are you even sure that your input exists  ? The tag is not well formed, you have a space between `<` and `input`.
And the correct command is getElementById, not ID.

Your javascript is correct, this put aside.

Comment: yes my input exists. here's the code "<input type="hidden" id="total" value="" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" runat="server" />". I did edited the tag getElementById. i just mistyped it when posting the question. will try it again. thanks